# Create a list in sheet 2 containing column 1&5 from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 columns 1&2, if Sheet 1 column 3 contains "yes"

Tags: google-sheets

I have sheet with 6 columns of data and 100 rows.  If Sheet 1, column 3 has the text  "yes" in it, I want to copy column 1 to column 1 and column 5 to column 2.

That's not too hard with a simple Match.  The problem is I don't want blank rows if column 3 doesn't have "yes" in it.  So for example:

**Sheet 1:**

```
Steve, Johnson, yes, 5, welder  
Ryan, Flag, yes, 3, welder  
Joe, Dirt, no, 0, forklift  
David, Abraham, yes, forklift  
Logan, Gonzales, yes, truck
```

**Sheet 2:**

```
Steve, welder  
Ryan, welder  
David, forklift  
Logan, truck
```

Comment: You only have 5 columns of data and last two rows are missing a column. But I completed a simply function which will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the names of the sheets in the getSheetByName functions if you need to.

```
function summaryList()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainsht=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Change sheetname if needed
  var mainrng=mainsht.getDataRange();
  var mainrngA=mainrng.getValues();
  var sumsht=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); //Change sheetname if needed
  var sumA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<mainrngA.length;i++)
  {
    if(mainrngA[i][2]=='yes')
    {
      sumA.push([mainrngA[i][0],mainrngA[i][4]]);
    }
  }
  if(sumA.length)
  {  
    var sumrng=sumsht.getRange(1,1,sumA.length,sumA[0].length);
    sumrng.setValues(sumA);
  }
  else
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No content in summary list');
  }

}
```

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you'd check off my answer.  Thanks